# Transparent Controls In VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm trying to add some windows forms controls to a worksheet using vsto.  I'd like them to be transparent though (so that the actual content in Excel is visible).

My winforms user control constructor looks like this:

```
    public Tag()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

I'm adding the control like this:

```
void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
  var nativeSheet = Wb.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

  if (nativeSheet != null)
  {
    var tag = new Tag();
    var vstoSheet = nativeSheet.GetVstoObject();
    var range = nativeSheet.Range["A1", missing];
    vstoSheet.Controls.AddControl(tag, range, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  }
}
```

If there's some content cell A1, it will be covered by the control (the cell will just appear as plain white).

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: +1, but some Microsoft folks have [answered this in the negative](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vsto/thread/20d3fe58-2bf4-49d3-8255-b0e3b32a42cc)...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned over at MSDN:

> When a Windows form control are hosted on Office document, the control
>   is not directly embedded in the document. An ActiveX control called
>   the Windows Forms control host is added to document surface first and
>   the control host acts as a host for each Windows Form control added
>   too the document.

You can see for yourself:

```
var btn = new ImageButton();
btn.Name = "link1";
btn.Text = controlText;
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(pic, nativeWorksheet.Range[address], controlText);


 public class ImageButton : Control, IButtonControl
    {
        public ImageButton()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, this.ClientRectangle);
        }    

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            // don't call the base class
            //base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
        }    

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
                return cp;
            }
        }    
        // rest of class here...          
    }
```